# stop redirect? watch code in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio to compile and run my ASP.NET website. Now, one of the pages have searchbox acting very odd, because it's redirecting to typical "FileNotFound" page which we're using to redirect when there is a typo in URL or something (and definitely not for searches).

The search is a separate .ascx control, so it's exactly the same for all pages.

So is there a way I can see what's happening behind the scenes to trigger that redirect? It is not firing the click event of the search button either, something is taking place even before the click??!

Is there a way I can watch the code run in Visual Studio without placing a breakpoint, because I do not know where to place it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Fiddler or Firebug to watch the requests and responses.  That might help diagnose where the redirect is happening.